# cant find error in unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python

Hello i am trying to rearrange a 2d list so that deals with name repetitions without using built in functions. but when i go to print i get this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

the problem code is

```
if c[i][0]==c[i+1][0] and c[c-1][0]!= c[i][0] :
```

and the code im hoping runs my program which i cant check because of the error is

```
d = []
d.append(c[0][0])
d.append(c[0][1])
i = 1
while size - 1 :
    # for more multiple repeats,append only classes
    if c[i][0]==c[i+1][0] and c[i-1][0]==c[i][0] :
        d.append(c[i][1])
        d.append(c[i+1][1])
    # for single repeats, append name, and classes
    if c[i][0]==c[i+1][0] and c[c-1][0]!= c[i][0] :
        d.append(c[i][0])
        d.append(c[i][1])
        d.append(c[i+1][1])
    # no  previous repeats, append name and class
    else :
        d.append(c[i][0])
        d.append(c[i][1])
    i = i + 1
print d
```

im not sure why it causes the error because the previous if statement caused no problem. maybe it has to do with the `!=` statement ? if you wanna run the code the list being processed is

```
[['Adam', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Ashley', 'IE 3312'], ['Ashley', 'PHYS 1443'], ['August', 'PHYS 1444'], ['Baron', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Christopher', 'IE 3301'], ['Christopher', 'CSE 1320'], ['Christopher', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Dylan', 'CSE 1310'], ['Henry', 'PHYS 1444'], ['James', 'IE 3301'], ['James', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Jonathan', 'IE 3312'], ['Krishna', 'CSE 1310'], ['Luis', 'CSE 1310'], ['Michael', 'IE 3301'], ['Nang', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Pramod', 'PHYS 1444'], ['Pramod', 'PHYS 1443'], ['Saroj', 'IE 3301'], ['Saroj', 'MATH 1426'], ['Sol', 'CSE 1310'], ['Timothy', 'MATH 2325'], ['Timothy', 'IE 3301']]
```

Answer (score 4):

`c` is the `list` you are accessing so I'm guessing it can't also be an `int`.

perhaps you meant:

```
if c[i][0]==c[i+1][0] and c[i-1][0]!= c[i][0] :
```

Comment: thanks, i didnt even see that. but now my list is out of range. darn

Comment: You could add a simple check for that, you want to stop it if the index goes out of bounds on either end.

Answer (score 2):

first error is `c` list as indesx in line

```
if c[i][0]==c[i+1][0] and c[c-1][0]!= c[i][0] :
```

And I think there is other error. can't see where `size` is decreased.

```
while size - 1 :
     ....
```

Maybe YOu meant

```
while size - i:
    ...
```